# Editorconfig - Allow underscore variable

Tags: c#, editorconfig

Is it possible to set up the editorconfig to allow complete underscore variables?

Example:

```cs
Changed += (_, __) => valueChanged?.Invoke(Value); // Allow the "__" or "___" or "____"
```

Thank u.

Comment: A single underscore in your context will be treated as a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) variable. Anyways why do you want underscores as variable names?

Comment: Yea, a single underscore will be treated as a discard. But what if u had two useless variables? (Like in the example)

Comment: Then just do `(_, _)`. You can use the discard variable as many times as you want. No need for multiple. The documentation I linked in my previous comment shows this: `var (_, _, _, pop1, _, pop2) = QueryCityDataForYears("New York City", 1960, 2010);`

Comment: Just try the following: 

`event EventHandler Changed;  
void RegisterAnonymEventHandlerUnderscore()
{
    Changed += (_, _) => Console.WriteLine("Something happend");
}`

It says: **The parameter name '_' is a duplicate**

Comment: Ah yes my bad. This is because discard variable can't be used in this context as you're declaring an anonymous lambda expression. So, do you get any error thrown or shown? When I try with `(_, __)` it works fine

Comment: Np. Nah the problem here is my editorconfig configuration. 
**Naming rule violation: Prefix '_' is not expected.** Caused by my naming rule wich only allows underscore for private variables/properties.

Comment: Then the answer is simply not to use it. I recommend you use `(sender, args)` as the EventHandler signature is `void Handler (object sender, EventArgs args)` (sometimes also `EventArgs e`)

Comment: There's also the `delegate` syntax, which allows you to keep the signature implicit: `Changed += delegate { valueChanged?.Invoke(value); }`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Would work, but now Stylecop don't like it :D

Comment: I tried StyleCop once, then discarded it as "clearly not for me". FxCop and friends (Roslyn analyzers) are great as they catch actual problems; StyleCop is only useful for enforcing team-wide standards. If you don't have those and are just using the defaults "because if Microsoft thought of it it must be good" it doesn't improve code one bit. (If you do have team-wide standards and they explicitly include "don't use `delegate`", it's another story.)

Comment: Yea, we use it for team-wide-standards. But thanks anyway :)